# VS2019 not properly importing Qt Designer project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019, qt-designer, qt6

I have looked everywhere for a solution to this, but I cannot find one. In VS2019, I have the Qt tools extension installed, and I have exported the C++ header file from Qt Designer including my project.
I then created a .pro file including:

```
QT += widgets
QT += uitools

HEADERS += ui_xinterface.h
FORMS += xinterface.ui
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I then imported this into VS2019, which created a project automatically. I then added this function to main.cpp, as per [this example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-uitools-approach) (note: main.cpp is originally an empty file):

```
#include <QtUiTools>
#include "ui_xinterface.h"

static QWidget* loadUiFile(QWidget* parent)
{
    QFile file(":/forms/xinterface.ui");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    QUiLoader loader;
    return loader.load(&file, parent);
}
```

This didn't build:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ui_interface, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.cpp
1>Qt6EntryPointd.lib(qtentrypoint_win.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function WinMain
1>debug\\ui_interface.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ui_interface.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And gave 9 errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  ui_interface    C:\Users\User\Documents\EE\basic-app\debug\ui_interface.exe 1   
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function WinMain  ui_interface    C:\Users\User\Documents\EE\basic-app\Qt6EntryPointd.lib(qtentrypoint_win.cpp.obj)   1   
Error (active)  E2422   defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr  ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h  444 
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value   ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h  2181    
Error (active)  E0028   expression must have a constant value   ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h  2261    
Error (active)  E2422   defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr  ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmutex.h 150 
Error (active)  E2422   defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr  ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qmutex.h 205 
Error (active)  E2422   defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr  ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qproperty.h  255 
Error (active)  E2422   defaulted default constructor cannot be constexpr because the corresponding implicitly declared default constructor would not be constexpr  ui_interface    C:\Qt\6.2.0\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore\qrunnable.h  56*
```

These seem like linker errors but I have no idea how to fix them. The additional libraries [$(Qt_INCLUDEPATH_)] and directories [$(Qt_LIBPATH_)] seems to be linked automatically in project properties. I'm quite new to this, what am I missing?

Comment: There's quite a few things going on but the first thing you need to fix is you need a `main()` function in your program! You can put it in your `main.cpp` file and let it call the other function you have there.

Comment: Are you using the Qt addon?

Comment: @ypnos I'm not sure what that changes. 'static' is a function in of itself so if I'm correct that should serve as the main function?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I am

Comment: You simply can't create an executable without providing an entry point (aka main()).

Comment: Ok. It runs. Now I have to figure out how to actually make it actually work